# ListViewAnimations library - Animate additions?

Tags: android, listview, animation

I've been having trouble implementing the animate additions functionality of nhaarman's ListViewAnimations library.

As specified in the wiki, I'm using the DynamicListView, and my ArrayAdapter implements Insertable.

However, things aren't working. A couple of questions:

Do I use a normal ArrayAdapter or do I have to use the library's ArrayAdapter? I've tried both. I suspect the correct answer is to use a normal ArrayAdapter and override the following function:

```
public void add(int i, @NonNull Comment comment)
```

If that's the case, what do I have to put inside this function? notifyDataSetChanged()?

Do I have to wrap my adapter in of the AnimationAdapters?

Comment: just do like this : [Link](http://nhaarman.github.io/ListViewAnimations/#animate-addition)

Comment: @Harry, yes I've seen that and I've followed it, but does MyInsertableAdapter extend ArrayAdapter or com.nhaarman.listviewanimations.ArrayAdapter?

Comment: Have you seen this comment there? -> // MyInsertableAdapter implements Insertable